# Right-to-left is messing up pixel positioning?

Tags: css-transforms, right-to-left

If I set up my html document as `dir=rtl`, all absolute positioned elements get moved to the right as expected but the translation is awkward. I need to move the elements to a negative position in order to center them correctly.

Removing the `rtl` solved the problem and everything retains the same Cartesian origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you normally correct `x` to the center of the element like this:

```
x = x * windowWidth - elm.clientWidth / 2; // x is a value in [0..1]
```

Then you will probably need to do something like:

```
x = (x -1) * windowWidth + elm.clientWidth / 2;
```

If you want to position normally then don't divide by 2.